# What is => mean in my bash script

Tags: bash

I have this line in a bash script and I can't figure out what the "=>" means? I don't think it means equal to or greater than but maybe it does. Thoughts?

```
"echo '\"postgres\" => { \"archive_timeout\" => 300, \"backup\" => 1, \"base_backup_interval\" => 3600, \"restore\" => 1 },' >> /tmp/user_data.config\n",
```

Comment: they just appending a string to user_data.config file.

Comment: It looks almost as if the line contains a string the contains/generates a shell echo command that appends a Perl hash element to a file.  Somewhat esoteric!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mean anything, because it's inside a string. Consider:

```
$ echo 'foo'
foo

$ echo 'foo => bar'
foo => bar
```

The `=>` doesn't have any significance; it's just part of the string that `echo` writes to its output.

In the case of your code, the `echo` command and its string argument are followed by `>> /tmp/user_data.config`, which just means that the output will be appended to the `user_data.config` file. Like so:

```
$ touch /tmp/out.txt
$ echo 'foo => bar' >> /tmp/out.txt
$ echo 'baz => qux' >> /tmp/out.txt
$ cat /tmp/out.txt
foo => bar
baz => qux
```

Comment: Hey downvoter; please take a moment to explain the reason for your downvote, so that I can take the opportunity to improve my answer.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but what's shown is a string containing an echo command, not an echo command.  There's a difference.  The overall conclusion "it is part of a string and has no other significance" is valid.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was better to answer the question than to quiz the user about where this code is coming from and why it's in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The `=>` is part of the string that is being echo'd. Try running the command (without the `"` at the beginning and the `\n",` at the end) in BASH and you'll see it just echoes the string and appends it to `/tmp/user_data.config`

```
$ echo '\"postgres\" => { \"archive_timeout\" => 300, \"backup\" => 1, \"base_backup_interval\" => 3600, \"restore\" => 1 },' >> /tmp/user_data.config
$ cat /tmp/user_data.config
\"postgres\" => { \"archive_timeout\" => 300, \"backup\" => 1, \"base_backup_interval\" => 3600, \"restore\" => 1 },
```